# Validando um campo do tipo input em função de um select

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, bootstrap

Estou trabalhando com Codeigniter/Bootstrap e preciso validar um campo do meu formulário em função de outro. Tenho um campo do tipo select chamado Contrato, com duas opções possíveis (Sim ou Não) e um outro campo do tipo input chamado DataContrato.
Preciso que quando a opção SIM for selecionada no select, o preenchimento do campo DataContrato se tornasse obrigatório.

Comment: Usa um javascript para isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P/ validar entes de enviar, torne obrigatório atribuindo required ao campo DataContrato a depender do valor do select Contrato. Eu usaria JQuery:

```
´$(function(){
    $('#IdContrato').change(function(){
     if($('#IdContrato').val()==='Sim'){
      $('#IdDataContrato').prop('required', true);
     }
    });
});´
```

Também é possível fazer uma validação condicional depois de enviar ([Veja no manual](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html?highlight=form_validation#setting-validation-rules)) **se vc estiver validando no controlador/método**. Basta criar uma condição dependente do valor enviado dentro das regras de validação do $this->form_validation->run().

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente.  Show de bola, obrigado !!!!

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um exemplo básico, não sei se é a melhor maneira, mas funciona.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script>
    
      function ativarInputDataContrato(){
        var lista = document.getElementById("lista-boolean-contrato");
        var input = document.getElementById("data-contrato");
        if(lista.value == "Sim"){
          input.disabled = false;
          input.required = true;
        }else{
          input.disabled = true;
          input.required = false;
        }
      }
      
      
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="formulario">
      Contrato:
       <select id="lista-boolean-contrato" onchange="ativarInputDataContrato()">
         <option value="Nao">Não</option>
         <option value="Sim">Sim</option>
         
       </select>
       <input id = "data-contrato" type = "date" disabled required="true" />
       <input type = "submit" value = "Enviar"/>
     </form>
  </body>

</html>
```